# Properties of Compactness in Hausdroff Spaces

Tags: general-topology

One of the supplementary problems from Schaum's General Topology states that if you have a compact subset of a Hausdorff space and a point not in the compact subset, there exist disjoint, open sets containing the point and the compact subset, respectively. The proof from the book is as follows:

---

[image]

---

Now, it's nice that the author is rigorous and careful about his proof but I postulate that there is an easier proof to this.

*Proof*

Let $A$ be a compact subset of a Hausdorff space $X$ and let $p \in X$ with $p \not\in A$.

Consider $a \in A$. Since $X$ is Hausdorff, for each $a \in A$ and $p \not\in A$, there exist disjoint open sets $G_a$ and $G_p$ such that $a \in G_a$ and $p \in G_p$.

Since the union of open sets is open, $\bigcup \{G_a\}$ is open.

Since $G_a \cap G_p = \varnothing$ for every $G_a$, $G_p \cap \bigcup\{G_a\}= \varnothing.$

We have shown now that $p \in G_p$ and $a \in A \subset \bigcup\{G_a\}$ and $G_p \cap \bigcup\{G_a\} =\varnothing$, which is what we were trying to prove.

---

I like my proof because it is simpler but I noticed that I completely failed to use compactness in my proof. I'm not seeing why compactness is even an essential part of the proof here. Because, if we know that each $x_1$ and $x_2$ in a Hausdorff space $X$ have disjoint open sets containing each, can't you just take each $x_i$ in the compact set, take the union of each open sets $U_{x_i}$ containing each $x_i$ and claim that $x_i \in \bigcup U_{x_i}$ and that $U_p \bigcap U_{x_i} = \varnothing$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need compactness because in your argument the neighborhood $G_p$ that you construct depends on a!

You say(paraphrasing): Given $a\in A$ and $p\notin A$, there exist disjoint neighborhoods $G_a$ and $G_p$ of $a$ and $p$...but this $G_p$ depends on $a$, so really the notation should be $G_{p,a}$ and then the neighborhood of $p$ that you want in the end is $\cap_{a\in A} G_{p,a}$, but this is a possibly infinite intersection of open sets, unless...

Comment: +1. The proposer's attempt could be given as a "Fake Proof" that every subset of a Hausdorff space is closed.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a counterexample: take $X = \mathbb R$, $A = [0,1)$, and $p = 1 \in X \setminus A$. I think you'll be able to see that every open subset $U \subset \mathbb R$ that contains $1$ has nonempty intersection with $[0,1)$, and therefore $U$ certainly has nonempty intersection with every open subset of $\mathbb R$ that contains $[0,1)$.

So if your proof did not even use compactness of $A$ then you can walk through your proof step-by-step with this counterexample, to see what step goes wrong.

Comment: Assuming that you’re talking about the natural topology on $\mathbb{R}$, the set $[0,1)$ is not compact as the Heine-Borel Theorem states that the only compact sets of $\mathbb{R}$ are exactly the closed and bounded sets, and $[0,1)$ is not closed. So $A=[0,1)$ is not a valid counterexample

Comment: It is not intended as a counterexample to the *statement*, it is intended as a counterexample to your **proof**. You claim your proof is correct and did not use compactness. If you are correct about that, then you have found a proof of the statement in your first paragraph except with the word "compact" removed.

Comment: Generally speaking, if you have a theorem of the form "If P and Q and R then S", and if you have proof of that theorem which does not ever use the hypothesis "P", and if that proof is *valid*, then you have actually proved a stronger theorem of the form "if Q and R then S".

Comment: I see what you mean now. So my proof doesn’t actually work. That’s why the compactness is needed

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: But here's an interesting thing: I've written wrong proofs, which I know **have** to be wrong because I discovered a counterexample to the theorem. It's then very instructive to walk through the proof that I thought I had, using that counterexample, to see where the proof went wrong.

Comment: thank you for the through and constructive feedback

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126381/discussion-between-sunroad2-and-lee-mosher).